# Image loading using Lazy Load

Tags: php, jquery, image, lazy-loading

I have used http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload this plugin to load the images.

It works fine when I scroll down the page images are loading but I need to display first row images when page is loaded.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

By default images are loaded when they appear on the screen. If you want images to load earlier you can set threshold parameter. Setting threshold to 200 causes image to load 200 pixels before it is visible.

```
$("img.lazy").lazyload({ threshold : 200 });
```

So in your case, how far is the first row down the page?

```
$(function() {
    var $firstRow = $('table:first tr:first'), 
    threshold = $firstRow.offset().top + $firstRow.height();
    $("img.lazy").lazyload({ threshold : threshold });
});
```

or something like that.

Comment: after using threshold : 200 it wont display images for my visible area. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: You are taking things too literally. How far down the page are they? You can do this by using the second approach, a selector to get the top location.

Comment: sorry, actually I asked wrong question, I want to know  what is threshold is it height of container or anything else?

Comment: @absolutek I added an example that might help you more. It finds the firstRow of the first table, gets the top and height then sets the threshold so it will show that first row.

Answer (score 0):

In Web site demo page running , is display first row with page is load see this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/r2c4G/)

```
$(function() {
          $("img").lazyload({
              effect : "fadeIn",
              /*
              appear : function(elements_left, settings) {
                  console.log("appear");
                  console.log(elements_left);
                  //console.log(this, elements_left, settings);
              },
              load : function(elements_left, settings) {
                  console.log("load");
                  console.log(elements_left);
                  //console.log(this, elements_left, settings);
              }
              */
          });
      });​
```

Answer (score 0):

Your images are missing width and height attributes. Lazy Load wont work properly without them. Without knowing width and height browser cannot know where images are supposed to be in the layout when `document.ready` event fires. Proper image tag looks something like following:

```
<img class="lazy" src="img/grey.gif" data-original="img/example.jpg"  width="640" heigh="480">
```